# Combining Images with Card Flip animation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to combine images and flip them using the function:

```
UIView.transitionFromView(self.frontImageView, toView: self.backImageView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
```

This is using swift. I have 2 views and it works fine. I would like the `backImageView` to be a combination of the card which looks like a card with empty white space, and a letter or an image.

I saw several posts on combining images using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

When I do this for letters it slows the app down I think..

Here is this code used (Card is a subclass of UIView)

```
func combineImages( card: Card ) -> UIImage
{
    let bottomImage: UIImage = UIImage( named: "cardFront" )!


    var textColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    var textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Muli", size: 120 )!

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( bottomImage.size )

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    ]

    bottomImage.drawInRect( CGRectMake(0, 0, bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height) )

    var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake( 50, 48, 380, 360 )

    var drawText = "\( card.pictureName )"
    drawText.drawInRect( rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes )

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    return newImage


}
```

Question is, is there a better way to do this? Something faster? I believe combining images is probably the slower alternative to something simple which i could be missing.